# Having trouble solving logic of random number game

Tags: java, oop, methods, logic

I am relatively new to java programming. I am currently working on building a mini guessing game, as a project to learn more Java. I am having some issues with the following:

Here are the 4 main things I am having trouble solving.

- Record the answer for each user, if incorrect.
- If the user was correct, skip them in subsequent rounds.
- Once all players have guessed their correct number, print out the number of guesses it took for each one to guess correctly, the incorrect responses, and show a ranking of the players.
- Ask if the user(s) wish to play again. If so, reset all values.

Here are the methods that I have written;

```
import java.io.*;

public class MultiPlayerRandomGame {

// this method asks how many users will be playing and returns the number of users
public static int howManyUsers() {

    System.out.println("How many users will be playing?");
    int players = IO.readInt();
    return players;
}

// this method generates and returns a random number 
public static int generateRandomNumber() {

    int randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
    return randomNumber;
}

// this method compares user's entered guess and the generated random number then returns true/false
public static boolean compareGuess(int guess, int randomNumbers) {

    boolean isGuessCorrect = false;

    if (guess == randomNumbers) {
        System.out.println("CORRECT!");
        isGuessCorrect = true;

    } else if (guess > randomNumbers) {
        System.out.println("Too High");

    } else if (guess < randomNumbers) {
        System.out.println("Too Low");
    }

    System.out.println("test1");
    return isGuessCorrect;
} 

// this method determines whether Player N is correct or incorrect
public static boolean nextPlayer(int numOfUsers, int[] numberOfGuesses, int[] randomNumbers, int[][] numberBoard) {

    for (int n = 0; n < numOfUsers; n++) {
        int guessedNumber = numberOfGuesses[n];

        /*      if (guessedNumber == 0) {
            return false;   
        }*/

        if (numberBoard[n][guessedNumber] != randomNumbers[n]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

/* this method is supposed to print out the number of guesses it took each player to guess their correct number
 * CORRECTION: change the logic of this method to printing the number of guesses for one player then
 * in the main method or wherever, make a for loop that prints out the number of guesses for each player
 */
public static void amountOfGuesses(int numOfUsers, int [] numberOfGuesses, int [][] numberBoard) {

    int n = 0;
    for ( int i = 0; i < numOfUsers; i++ ) {
        n = n + 1;
        System.out.println("Player " + n + " guessed " + numberOfGuesses[i]+ " time(s)");
    }
}

// this method determines whether the user(s) would like to play again
public static boolean playAgain(String answer) {

    boolean userWillPlayAgain;

    if (answer.compareToIgnoreCase("no") == 0) {
        userWillPlayAgain = false;
    }
    else {
        userWillPlayAgain = true;
    }
    return userWillPlayAgain;
}

// this method controls the entire game
public static boolean playGame(){

    boolean gameTerminate = false;
    int numOfUsers = howManyUsers();
    int [] randomNumbers = new int[numOfUsers];
    int [] numberOfGuesses = new int [numOfUsers];  
    int [][] numberBoard = new int [numOfUsers][100];

    // this for loop assigns the n random number(s) to the n player(s)
    for (int n = 0; n < numOfUsers; n++){
        randomNumbers[n] = generateRandomNumber(); 
        System.out.println("PLAYER " + (n+1) + "'s RANDOM NUMBER: " + randomNumbers[n]);
    }

    do { 
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfUsers; i++) {
            int guessedNumber = numberOfGuesses[i];

            if (guessedNumber == 0 || numberBoard[i][guessedNumber-1] != randomNumbers[i]) {
                System.out.println("Enter your guess Player " + (i+1) + ":");
                int enteredGuess = IO.readInt();


                numberBoard[i][guessedNumber] = enteredGuess;
                numberOfGuesses[i] = guessedNumber + 1;

                if(compareGuess(enteredGuess, randomNumbers[i])){
                    return true;

                }
            }
        } 

        /* int n = 0;
         * for ( int j = 0; j < numOfUsers; j++ ) {
            n = n + 1;
            System.out.println("Player " + n + " guessed " + numberOfGuesses[j]+ " time(s)"); }
         */


    } while (nextPlayer(numOfUsers, numberOfGuesses, randomNumbers, numberBoard) == false);


    // System.out.println("test"); 
    return gameTerminate;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    boolean playing = true;
    while (playing) {
        playGame();

        System.out.println("Would you like to play again?");
        String answer = IO.readString();

        playing = playAgain(answer);
    }
    System.out.println("OK, goodbye!");
  }
}
```

Main issue as of right now: The game terminates and asks if user would like to play again after a player guesses their number, rather than after every player guesses their number.

Do I need actual Objects to make this happen and track every player or can this still be solved without objects? This is a territory I am unfamiliar with.

Answer (score 1):

Right now your `playGame` method returns `true` back to `main` whenever any guess returns correct from `compareGuess`.

I would recommend setting up another array `boolean[] correctGuess` in `playGame` and mark the player number index as `true` if a player guesses correctly. You can use this new array to skip players who have guessed correctly, also. Once all players are marked true you can return to `main`.

Answer (score 0):

This won't help improve your current code, but the same game can easily implemented using objects. In my opinion, the code is cleaner and easier to read.

Objects allow you to encapsulate the data required by each class. The target, number of guesses, and whether they were correct is stored in the `Person` object instead of in a multi-dimensional array. The values can be accessed by referencing the `Person` object - e.g. `person.numGuesses` or `person.target`.

By using objects, you can keep specific functionality scoped out of the main class. i.e. abstract away the implementation. In a future version of the game, you may want to change the way the target value is incremented; by using objects, the change can be made in the class which sets and checks the value - without affecting any other classes.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Game {

    private final List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();

    private Game(int numPlayers) {

        for (int i = 0; i < numPlayers; i++) {
            personList.add(new Person(i)); // Fill the player list
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.print("Enter the number of players: ");

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numPlayers = sc.nextInt();

        // Initialise with the number of players
        Game g = new Game(numPlayers);
        g.mainLoop(); // Play the game

        boolean playAgain = false;

        do {

            System.out.print("Do you wish to play again?: ");
            String in = sc.next();

            playAgain = "yes".equals(in);

            if (playAgain) {
                g.resetAll();
                g.mainLoop();
            }

        } while (playAgain); // Only loop if they answered "yes"

    }

    private boolean allCorrect() {
        // Check if all players have answered correctly
        return personList.stream().allMatch(p -> p.correct);
    }

    private void resetAll() {
        for (Person p : personList) {
            p.reset(); // Reset each person
        }
    }

    private void mainLoop() {

        while (!allCorrect()) {
            for (Person p : personList) {
                p.doGuess(); // Ask for the guess
            }
        }

        // Everyone is correct, print the scores.

        for (Person p : personList) {
            System.out.println("Player " + p.id + " => " + p.numGuesses + " guesses");
        }

    }

}

class Person {

    final int id;
    int numGuesses;
    boolean correct;

    private int target;

    Person(int id) {
        this.id = id;
        target = new Random().nextInt(100); // Each player has a random target between 0-100
    }

    void doGuess() {

        if (correct) {
            // Skip turn if they're already correct
            return;
        }

        numGuesses++;

        System.out.print("Player " + id + " guess " + numGuesses + "(" + target + "): ");

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i = sc.nextInt(); // Read the guess

        if (i == target) {
            correct = true;
            System.out.println("Correct!");
        }

    }

    void reset() {
        target = new Random().nextInt(100); // New target between 0-100
        numGuesses = 0; // Reset the counter
        correct = false;
    }
}
```